# SQL: Struggling writing SQL Script

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL: I am trying to write a script that runs the details of daily transaction for an entire month.

I want to create 3 variables:

```
month ,
begin_date ,
end_date ,
```

This way when running the script for the next month, I only have to update these variables once, instead of updating every line.

Ideally I would like the script to perform a specific query for a specific client.

```
`month = 'April'
begin_date ='2018-04-01'
end_date = '2018-04-30'


SELECT date,client,price
FROM clientdb
WHERE date >= begin_date and date <= end_date and client='xxxx' `
```

I would like the results of this query saved (preferreably as an .xlsx) as: month + 'xxxx'

Then run the next client

```
SELECT date,client,price
FROM clientdb
WHERE date >= begin_date and date <=end_date and client='yyyy'
```

Then save the results as month + 'yyyy' `

Then so on so forth.....

Struggling to find any resources -- any feedback would greatly appreciated!

Comment: PostgreSQL knows nothing about MS Excel, but both can to deal with CSV/TSV formats. Look at the [`copy` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are going to run the script. Assuming this is Linux, you could use the date function to feed your SQL script. Something like this :

```
/myReportExport.sh `date -d "-1 months" +%Y-%m` `date -d "-2 months" +%Y-%m` `date -d "-1 months" +%m/01/%Y` > myreport.csv
```

Provide more information on your environment, and I may be able to help more. There is no built-in Postgres to Excel function though. This will require a third party tool or use Excel ODBC to perform the query.